# Exclude a specific email address from form submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I have seen this question asked elsewhere but am unsure of how to put some validation into my particular form which will exclude a particular email address. I would like the form to be rejected if an email address is entered, lets say anything@anything.com. Please see code below. There is more but i believe this is the relevant part...

```
$errors = array();

// Remove $_COOKIE elements from $_REQUEST.

if(count($_COOKIE)){
   foreach(array_keys($_COOKIE) as $value){
       unset($_REQUEST[$value]);
   }
}

// Validate email field.

if(isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']))
{
    $_REQUEST['email'] = trim($_REQUEST['email']);

    if(substr_count($_REQUEST['email'],"@") != 1 ||
       stristr($_REQUEST['email']," ") || 
       stristr($_REQUEST['email'],"\\") || 
       stristr($_REQUEST['email'],":") ){
           $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
    }
    else{
        $exploded_email = explode("@",$_REQUEST['email']);
        if (empty($exploded_email[0]) || 
            strlen($exploded_email[0]) > 64 || 
            empty($exploded_email[1])){
               $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
        }
        else{
           if(substr_count($exploded_email[1],".") == 0){
               $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
           }
           else{
               $exploded_domain = explode(".",$exploded_email[1]);
               if(in_array("",$exploded_domain)){
                   $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
               }
               else{
                   foreach($exploded_domain as $value){
                       if(strlen($value) > 63 || 
                          !preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i',$value)){
                              $errors[] = "Email address is invalid"; 
                              break;
                        }
                   }
               }
            }
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: what about `if (trim($_REQUEST['email']) == 'anything@anything.com') // reject`?

Comment: you want to exclude **1** e-mail adress or **certain** e-mail adresses

Comment: Use a black list, store it in your DB and query it each login attemp.

Comment: To exclude multiple email addresses would be ideal. Its a form which posts rather than a login system.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, the goal of the main part is to validate the format of the email given by the user.

First of all, there is a built-in php function for this ( PHP >= 5.2 ) : `filter_var()`. You can replace all this block of code with :

```
$email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
if (!filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
}
```

Then, if you want to check the email is not in a blacklist, just do something like this :

```
// Fill this array the way you want : hard-write it, fetch from database... 
$blacklist = array("email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"); 
// Put in lower case for easiest comparison
$email = strtolower($email);
if (in_array($email, $blacklist)) {
    $errors[] = "Email address is blacklisted";
}
```